# Sails.js Refer to a Package Globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, sails.js

I am using Sails a lot nowadays and I have a practice question. Right now when I want to use a NPM package over and over in a project I put something like this in my `config/bootstrap.js` file:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

  sails.Q = require('q');
  sails.url = require('url');
  ...

  cb();
};
```

I do this to use a package like Q in any controller without having to `require('q')` several times. I just do `sails.Q.[...]` when I need it. Is there a better way to achieve the same thing? I would rather be able to refer to the package by `Q.[...]` instead of `sails.Q.[...]`. Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If it's simply to save keystrokes, you really should just add

```
var Q = require('q')
```

at the top of each file you use it in. `require()` does not re-evaluate the module each time. After the first call, invoking it just fetches the exports of the module from cache, so there's no overhead to using it once per file.

If however, you acknowledge that it's poor practice and you're alright with that, you can export it globally like this:

```
global.Q = require('q')
```

That will allow you to reference `Q` from any file.

Answer (score -1):

You can do `var Q = require('q');` in *app.js* just before the server is started (i.e `sails.lift(rc('sails'));`).